# row count incorrectly displayed as 0 in redshift

Tags: count, redshift

I have a table in redshift with columns user_id and some_property, neither of which are unique.

The following query returns 0:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM table
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM table WHERE some_property = 1)
```

Suggesting that for every user_id in the table, there is an entry with some_property=1.

However if I run

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM table
```

then it returns a number greater than

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM table WHERE some_property = 1
```

To me this is a logical contradiction. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is `user_id` guaranteed to be NOT NULL?

Answer (score 2):

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    t 
AS
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
(
    VALUES
        (   1,    1),
        (   2,    0),
        (NULL,    1)
) AS x (user_id, some_property) ;
```

The SELECT COUNT from the original poster returns 0, the second one returns 2, and the last one returns 1.

---

Let's see why:

If you **take out the counts** and retrieve the rows, we get:

(1)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    user_id
FROM 
    t
WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM t WHERE some_property = 1) ;

|---------|
| user_id |
|---------|
```

(that is: nothing. The count, in this case, is clearly 0)

(2)

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM t ;

|---------|
| user_id |
|---------|
|   NULL  |
|---------|
|    1    |
|---------|
|    2    |
|---------|
```

(there are 3 rows, but the count is 2, because you don't count NULL)

And last,

(3)

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM t where some_property = 1 ;

|---------|
| user_id |
|---------|
|    1    |
|---------|
|   NULL  |
|---------|
```

(There are 2 rows, but Count is 1, because, again, you don't count NULL).

---

You have to take into account that, according to SQL standard:

```
a NOT IN (x, y, z)                is equivalent to   
NOT (a IN (x, y, z))              which in turn, is equivalent to
NOT (a = x OR a = y OR a = z)
```

If `a IS NULL`, you get `NOT (NULL = x OR NULL = y OR NULL = z)` which is `NULL`, regardless of the values of `x`, `y` or `z`.

Comment: You should correct the "*`a not in (x, y, z)` is equivalent to `(a = x OR a = y OR a = z)`*". It's not correct.

Comment: (About the 2 and 1 -> 3 and 2) yeah, your wording is a bit misleading/confusing. You are referring to the counts from the OP's queries but you are displaying queries without COUNTs, which return 3 and 2 rows respectively..

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Thx for the correction and suggestion. I've tried to make it a bit more clear.